# Ошибка при заливе дистрибутива на pypi.org: HTTPError: 400 Client Error: home_page: Invalid URI for url

Tags: python, pip

Вроде все нормально было, дистрибутив уже собранный, осталось только залить....

Не хочет, возвращает:

```
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: home_page: Invalid URI for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy
```

Пробовал подключиться с конфига, такая же малинка, не знаю, что делать.
Помогите, если вы уже с таким сталкивались и знаете решение проблемы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106954

Comment: правильную ссылку для домашней страницы вашего пакета укажите (url параметр в setup.py)